# need to get date from string through Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings that are similar to the ones below:

```
string str1 = "test_20150505";
string str2 = "test_20150505_yts";
string str3 = "test_all";
string str4 = "test";
```

The below regex code extracts date (`20150505`) for string `str1` and for string `str3` & string `str4` returns empty, which is also fine.

However, what do I have to change so as to extract date for string `str2`?

```
string d = Regex.Match(str1, "^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{8})(?:\\..*)?$").Groups[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you need `(?:\\..*)?` part in your regex? Non of yours examples dates ends with `.`.

Comment: Are all the dates in the YYYYMMDD format?

Answer (score 2):

You can just check for optional `_`s around 8-digits numbers:

```
(?<=_|\b)[0-9]{8}(?=_|\b)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D_%7C%5Cb)%5B0-9%5D%7B8%7D(%3F%3D_%7C%5Cb)&i=test_20150505%0D%0Atest_20150505_yts%0D%0Atest_all%0D%0Atest)

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=_|\b)[0-9]{8}(?=_|\b)");
var inputs = "test_20150505\n\test_20150505_yts\ntest_all\ntest";
var results = rx.Matches(inputs).OfType<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

[image]

Then, you can parse the date, e.g.:

```
DateTime datetime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(results[0], "yyyyMMdd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datetime);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your last part of the regex pattern seems to be a typo. Use

```
string d = Regex.Match(str1, "^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{8})(?:_.*)?$").Groups[1].Value.ToString();
```

instead.